# 2000 + (50% of 15%) | Simple math.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

As displayed in the title - we have: $$2000 + (50\%\text{ of }15\%)$$

Can you please tell me what answer you arrive at when calculating the above?

Comment: Fraction calculation: $$2000 + \frac12 \times \frac {3}{20}$$ Not so a logical result...

Answer (score 1):

"the_candyman" seems to be interpreting "2000+ (50% of 15%)" to mean "200+ (50% of 15% **of 2000**) but I don't see how that is necessarily so.

It certainly is true that, without interpreting (50% of 15%) as meaning "50% of 15% of **something**" it simply doesn't mean anything.  "2000" is a number. "50% of 15%" is an "operator"- it makes no sense to add them.  Please check the problem again and let us know: "50% of 15% of **what**?"

Comment: Well, this is exactly my problem. This is a question I was tasked with answering during a job interview today. I was certain the answer they were looking for was 2150, but I was reluctant to give such an answer as the formatting of the question seemed terribly off.

So, to clarify: this is not possible to calculate? 

Thanks for the feedback, both.

Comment: Its not an uncommon language construction to state a number plus a percentage as its usually implied the percentage is related to the previously stated number. Its more of a language thing than a math thing. Of course if the problem really is stated incorrectly...